# ajax get does not works correctly in freemarker

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, freemarker

I'm trying to display a user list on the screen using ajax. however, instead I get only an object. That is, the data in the ftlh file for some reason does not come. Help, why is this happening? and how to solve the problem.

This is the controller's code:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> userList = service.getAllUsers();
        List<UserResponse> users = new ArrayList<>();

        userList.forEach(user->
            users.add(new UserResponse(user.getUuid(),
                    user.getUsername(),
                    user.getEmail(),
                    user.getRole(),
                    user.getBalance(),
                    user.getState()))
        );
        return ResponseEntity.ok(users);
    }
```

This is freemarker's code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>User List</h1>
    <table id="user-table" class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/users",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(users) {
                users.forEach(function(user) {
                    let row = $("<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + user.uuid + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + user.username + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + user.email + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>");
                    $("#user-table tbody").append(row);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to change the @RestController to a @Controller, return strings, return the method itself, but nothing helps. Help me solve the problem please

Answer (score 0):

I copied this and run it and didn't have too many issues, I just had to make sure that `UserResponse` had the appropriate getters so that the serialization would work. Obviously, you can just visit `/users` to check you're getting JSON back.

Where I suspect you're going wrong is that there's something in the data so that your simple concat to build the row is creating invalid HTML.
Try this instead:

```js
let row = $("<tr>").append(
    $("<td>").text(user.uuid),
    $("<td>").text(user.username),
    $("<td>").text(user.email)
);
```